# Ember.js multiple, named outlet usage

Tags: ember.js, outlet

I have an application, which will have a view layer organized in three parts:

1. Sidebar
2. Toolbar-left
3. Toolbar-right

I have spent may last few hours with trying to find something helpful with google, but I had no luck. I would need a short and complete application example on how to do this using Router and connectOutlet, with named outlets.

Thx ahead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE: This code is outdated, due to the Ember api changes.**

I have reached a point, where I can say that I found the solution which is best for myself.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
<div class="container">
    <div class="toolbar">{{outlet toolbar}}</div>
    <div class="main">{{outlet dashboard}}</div>
    <div class="sidebar">{{outlet sidebar}}</div>
</div>
</script>
```

Using such a application template, I can choose where to render views. Like this:

```
App.router = Ember.Router.create({
    enableLogging: true,
    location: 'history',
    root: Ember.Route.extend({
        index: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/admin/',
            redirectsTo: 'login'
        }),
        login: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/admin/login/',
            doLogin: function(router, context) {
                "use strict";
                router.transitionTo('dashboard', context);
            },
            connectOutlets: function (router, context) {
                "use strict";
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('login', "login");
            }
        }),
        dashboard: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/admin/dashboard/',
            doLogout: function(router, context) {
                "use strict";
                router.transitionTo('login', context);
            },
            connectOutlets: function (router, context) {
                "use strict";
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('sidebar', 'sidebar');
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('toolbar', 'toolbar');
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('dashboard', 'dashboard');
            }
        })
    })
});
```

I have the three views, which are not important from the solution point of view, those get rendered to their outlets.

Hope this helps others.

Comment: I should mention that this code no longer works with the newest version of Ember.

Answer (score 59):

With the new Router you can do something like this:

```
{{outlet "menu"}}
{{outlet}}
```

In your Route you can handle the content of the outlets:

```
// application route
Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        // Render default outlet   
        this.render();
        // render extra outlets
        this.render("menu", {
            outlet: "menu",
            into: "application" // important when using at root level
        });
    }
});
```

You should have an `menu`-template though.

You can read more about it [here](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.13/classes/Route/methods/render?anchor=render).

Comment: I think that this is the most useful area of the documentation: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_render

Answer (score 11):

In your application template, you'll need to declare a named outlet as `{{outlet sidebar}}`. Likewise for the toolbars you mentioned.

EDIT: The rest is out of date. As @dineth said, see [Rendering a Template](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template).

<s>Then in your route (lets say `App.NavigationView` is what you want to stick there):</s>

```
App.Router = Em.Router.extend({    
    root: Em.Route.extend({
        index: Em.Route.extend({
            route: '/',
            connectOutlets: function(router) {
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('sidebar', 'navigation');
            }
        })
    })
});
```

Sidebar example: http://jsfiddle.net/q3snW/7/

Reference [this documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_outlet) on the `{{outlet}}` helper, and [this documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ControllerMixin.html#method_connectOutlet) on the `.connectOutlet` callback.

Comment: The jsfiddle example helped. I think I finally got the point.

Comment: Btw, the documentation is not good at all, it is missing the most important thing that one needs to understand it: the context.

Comment: I believe this solution is now outdated on Ember.JS. Refer to the documentation: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/