# emberjs 1.0 routing, unable to display named outlet

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Emberjs 1.0-pre router can’t find state for path and says router is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281815/emberjs-1-0-pre-router-cant-find-state-for-path-and-says-router-is-undefined)

Any advice on this will be helpful. I want the template named **data-template-name="logging** to display the outlet named **{{outlet mine }}** . For now using this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CNydA/4/)**, only the template named  **data-template-name="application** can display this named outlet, and i have to manually call **App.router.transitionTo('root.logon.index')** from the console for that to happen. I will want the named outlet to be displayed automatically without manually calling **transitionTo**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  <h1>Hi Friend</h1>
  {{outlet}}
  {{outlet mine }}
```

```
 <br/>
 <p><b>help</b></p>
```

```
 {{view  Ember.TextField placeholder="what" class="userInput"  }}
   <p> lets see</p>
    {{outlet mine }}
```

​

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  enableLogging:  true,
  location: 'hash',
  root: Ember.Route.extend({

    showLogin: Ember.Route.transitionTo('root.logon'),

    index:  Ember.Route.extend({
      route:  '/',

      connectOutlets:  function(router){
      router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('login');
    }

    }),

    logon:  Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/login',
      enter: function ( router ){
        console.log("The login sub-state was entered.");
    },
     connectOutlets:  function(router, context){
       router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet( 'login');
     },


     index: Ember.Route.extend({
       route: '/',
       connectOutlets: function(router) {
      router.get('loginController').connectOutlet('mine', 'login');
     }
   })          

  })

 })
```

});

Comment: Both of your recent questions are about named outlets.. have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150624/ember-js-multiple-named-outlet-usage)?

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe thanks for pointing out that link. I used that question as guide for creating the named outlet which you can see in the code that i pasted with this question as {{outlet mine }}. But thanks for still pointing it out.

Comment: I'll try this out later. Just another thing that you might wanna do.. reference `ember-latest` instead of any pre release, as it usually has the latest bugfixes and enhancements.

Comment: thanks @MilkyWayJoe. I finally got everything working and since this question is related to my other question, i posted the solution there and will add **[the link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281815/emberjs-1-0-pre-router-cant-find-state-for-path-and-says-router-is-undefined)**.