# Emberjs - How to access the current state or route name in RC1?

Tags: ember.js, router

In RC1 how can I get the currentstatename or current route name globally?

More specific, alternate syntax of :
**App.get('router').currentState.name;**

Comment: It is my answer an analogic question:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31994957/4205051

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at the answer to this question: [Ember App.Router.router.currentState undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019212/ember-app-router-router-currentstate-undefined/15020704#15020704)

Short answer: The current state is stores in the ApplicationController under the name "currentPath".