# Get current route name in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I need to get the current route name in my ember application; I tried this:
[Ember App.Router.router.currentState undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019212/ember-app-router-router-currentstate-undefined/15020704#15020704)
but it doesn't work for me (there is probablig something i'm missimg...) I use Ember rc6 and I have a multilingual app; in the applicationRoute I detect the browser's language and I redirect to the correct page with:

`this.transitionTo(userLang);`

but I would like this to be executed only when user are on the home page, so something like this:

```
if (currentRoute == 'home'){
  this.transitionTo(userLang)
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emberjs - How to access the current state or route name in RC1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318981/emberjs-how-to-access-the-current-state-or-route-name-in-rc1)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

NOTE: as of Ember 3.16, the original answer is not only recommended, but observers are strongly discouraged.

To get the current route name, you can utilize the Router Service: https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.18/classes/RouterService/properties/currentRouteName?anchor=currentRouteName

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  @service router;

  get activeRoute() {
    return this.router.currentRouteName;
  }
}
```

---

Original answer below

---

You could observe the `application`'s `currentPath` and set it to the current route accordingly when it changes:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  currentPath: '',
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  updateCurrentPath: function() {
    App.set('currentPath', this.get('currentPath'));
  }.observes('currentPath')
}),
```

This way you have access to the `currentPath` when ever you want with `App.get('currentPath');`

E.g.

```
if (App.get('currentPath') == 'home'){
  this.transitionTo(userLang);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, the thing is that if i do 'console.log(App.get("currentPath"))' inside the controller, I can see that it works; but i need to access currentPath from inside the redirect method of the ApplicationRoute, and here it doesn't work (the console log here shows that currentPath has no value)... Probably currentPath is updated only after the redirect method is called...

Comment: Also doing everything from the controller works (so now i don't need the redirect method of ApplicationRoute anymore); thanks for help...

Comment: I'm trying to do this in the Ember App Kit, where the 'App' global namespace has been replaced with the ES6 module transpiler. Since App.set and App.get don't work, how do I access 'currentPath'? Thanks!

Comment: @intuitivepixel , Thanks, But I have observed that there is a problem with params. For example If I have:  'this.resource('detail', { path: '/detail/:type' }, function() {});'  the currentPath is datail.index. I need to know the type. Can you help me?

Answer (score 26):

This worked for me on 1.3.0-beta (and a quick glance at the source for 1.1.2 suggests it would work there too):

```
App.__container__.lookup('router:main').location.lastSetURL
```

Note that the documentation states:

> At present, it relies on a hashchange event existing in the browser.

However, I believe it's strongly suggested that `App.__container__` not be used in production code. A more acceptable alternative would be to use `App.Router.router.currentHandlerInfos`, which provides information on the current Ember route.

Yet another option is `currentRouteName` on the `ApplicationController`. You can add `needs: ['application']` to your controller, then access the route name with `controllers.application.currentRouteName`. This will return something like `posts.index`.

Comment: I can confirm that it works with 1.2.0. But you must be careful, it does not work after the initial load of the application, even if it is a deep link; only after making a transition, it will return the correct value.

Comment: Not only does `App.Router.router.currentHandlerInfos` contain information about the current Ember route including its context (read: model), it also contains similar information for all parent routes. If you need these data, it really is the way to go!

Comment: `App.__container__.lookup()` is tremendously useful.

Answer (score 18):

With the shift to components, it is harder to get route name.  The best way is to add an initializer such as

```
ember g initializer router
```

(from command line), and

```
export function initialize(application) {
  application.inject('route', 'router', 'router:main');
  application.inject('component', 'router', 'router:main');
}

export default {
  name: 'router',
  initialize
};
```

in a initializers/router.js.  You can also inject into controller if you need to.  Then just do simply

```
this.get('router.currentRouteName');
```

in JS, or

```
{{router.currentRouteName}}
```

in template.

This is the only way I have found to get it reliably, and observable in Ember 2.4

Comment: Very nice indeed sir

Comment: This worked for me in Ember 2.7, thank you so much! This was also helpful to understand what is going on - especially the last answer about watching the route for changes: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-get-current-route-name/10324/7

Comment: I used this info to help build this component: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39395911/emberjs-2-7-how-to-bind-attribute-disabled-for-a-button/39396958#39396958

Comment: Injecting services by default is considered a bad practice in modern ember. You should define a service and inject it where needed. The `EmberRouter` is not even a service but just used as one here. I would strongly recommend to use `RouterService` added in Ember 2.15 instead.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to get current route in your component or controller you can inject routing service (`routing: Ember.inject.service('-routing')`)

(for [more](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/applications/dependency-injection/)) and use:

`this.get('routing.currentRouteName')` or `this.get('routing.currentPath')`

**Example with component** and computed property:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  routing: Ember.inject.service('-routing'),

  checkMyRouteName: Ember.computed('routing.currentRouteName',  function() {
    return this.get('routing.currentRouteName');
  })
})
```

**Example with controller** and computed property:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  routing: Ember.inject.service('-routing'),

  checkMyRouteName: Ember.computed('routing.currentRouteName', function() {
    return this.get('routing.currentRouteName');
  })
})
```

Current route in your route you just need `this.routeName`

**Example with route**:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  checkMyRouteName() {
    return this.routeName;
  }
})
```

Comment: You should not use private `-routing` service anymore. A public `RouterService` has been added in Ember 2.15 and is polyfilled for Ember >= 2.4.

Comment: @jelhan Yes, you are right. I didn't update it. For example, now I am using 3.8 version and there is: 

import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

router: service(),

get(this, 'router.currentRouteName')


Today I learned that I have to write which version I refer when I reply on StackOverflow, cause I even don't remember which version was when I wrote it :)

Answer (score 13):

Just as an update, in Ember 1.8.1, we can get the routeName inside an Ember.Route object by doing `this.routeName`.

Comment: how do I get it in an integration test? **currentRouteName** is undefined

Comment: `this.routeName` returns "application" when called from the application route, not very useful... Something like route.sub.sub would have been great.

Answer (score 3):

Currently as of Ember 1.7.0 you can get the current route from within a route by calling `this.routeName`.

Answer (score 3):

The Ember namespace API now has a [`getOwner`](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_getOwner) method, which is very useful for looking up the `currentRouteName`, or, other route properties.

```
  const owner        = Ember.getOwner(this);
  const currentRoute = owner.lookup('router:main').currentRouteName;
  const routeInfo    = owner.lookup(`route:${currentRoute}`).get('info');
  // etc.
```

I've created an [Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/21e3cc4a7f1c10eb08df9a1c2279d61e?openFiles=components.fixed-header.js%2Ctemplates.components.fixed-header.hbs&route=%2Fgreen) example to demonstrate. Use the text input above the "Output" pane to hit other routes like `/blue`, `/green`, or `/red`.

Comment: Please note that `currentRouteName` property of `EmberRouter` is not only private but even [undocumented](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.12/classes/EmberRouter). You should use public [`RouterService`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.12/classes/RouterService) instead, which was added in Ember 2.15 and is polyfilled for Ember >= 2.4.

Answer (score 2):

Ember has a [`RouterService`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.12/classes/RouterService) since 2.15. It provides the name of the current route as [`currentRouteName` property](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.12/classes/RouterService/properties/currentRouteName?anchor=currentRouteName). A [polyfill](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-router-service-polyfill) exists for Ember 2.4 - 2.14 if you are still on such an old version.

```js
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  router: service(),

  isHomeRoute: computed('router.currentRouteName', function() {
    return this.router.currentRouteName === 'home';
  }),
});
```

All other solutions mentioned here are relying on private API that might already be deprecated / removed. Using `RouterService` is working at least up the current version, which is `3.12` at the time of writing this.

Please note that the `"home"` is not `/`. The root URL is called `"index"`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for a while. then i started exploring router. It always have a state object which can be obtained from any route using

```
var route = this;
var handlerInfos = route.get("router.router.state.handlerInfos");
var currRouteHandlerInfo = handlerInfos[handlerInfos.length-1];
var currRouteName = currRouteHandlerInfo.name; //"home"
```

that's it. Now you have the current route name!

if you want the current route params,

```
var routerParams = this.get("router.router.state.params");
var currRouteParams = routerParams[currRouteName]; //{ homeId : "1" }
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me on the route.js file:
`this.controller.target.currentPath`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

You can simple parse the current URL. This way you can use your full url for example:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.html/#/home
```

and extract from this string the suffix:

```
/home
```

which is the current route name.

A simple JS function (that works regardless to your Ember version) will be:

```
function getCurrentRoute()
{
    var currentRoute;
    var currentUrl = window.location.href; // 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.html/#/home'

    var indexOfHash = currentUrl.indexOf('#');
    if ((indexOfHash == -1) ||
        (indexOfHash == currentUrl.length - 1))
    {
        currentRoute = '/';
    }
    else
    {
        currentRoute = currentUrl.slice(indexOfHash + 1); // '/home'
    }

    return currentRoute;
}
```

Example of use:

```
if (getCurrentRoute() == '/home')
{
// ...
}
```