# How to get store name of Ember Data model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How can I determine the "store name" (not sure what the proper terminology is) for a given ED Model? Say I have `App.Payment`, is there a store method that let's me look up its corresponding name, i.e. `payment` (for example to use in `find` queries)?

Comment: You can call the store from every controller/router you are in. So it is not necessarily attached to a route or function. To get the current route that relates to your store name, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302463/get-current-route-name-in-ember

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**For Ember Data 1.0 (and later)**

`modelName` is a dasherized string. It stored as a class property, so if you have an instance of a model:

```
var model = SuperUser.create();
console.log(model.constructor.modelName); // 'super-user'
```

---

*For Ember Data Pre 1.0*

`typeKey` is the string name of the model. It gets stored as a class property of the model, so if you have an instance of a model:

```
var model = App.Name.create({});
console.log(model.constructor.typeKey); // 'name'
```

Comment: here `model.get("type").typeKey` can be used instead.

Comment: This is definitely the better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for Ember's string dasherize method:

```
var fullClassName = "App.SomeKindOfPayment";
var className = fullClassName.replace(/.*\./, ""); // => "SomeKindOfPayment"
var dasherizedName = Ember.String.dasherize(className); // "some-kind-of-payment"
```

There might be a built-in way to do this in Ember, but I haven't found it after spending some time looking.

EDIT: Ember Data might also let you get away with passing "App.SomeKindOfPayment" when a model name is needed - it usually checks the format of the model name and updates it to the required format by itself.

Answer (score 0):

`store.find`, `store.createRecord`, and other persistence methods, use the `store.modelFor('myModel')`. After some setup it call `container.lookupFactory('model:' + key);` where key is the 'myModel'. So any valid factory lookup syntax is applicable. For example:

Given a model called `OrderItems` you can use: `order.items`, `order_items`, `order-items`, `orderItems`.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out there was no need to do this after all, and here's why:

I was trying to the the string representation of the model ("`payment`" for `App.Payment`) in order to call `store.findAll("payment")`. However, looking at the [ED source for `store`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js), the `findQuery` function calls `modelFor` to look up the factory (`App.Payment`) from the string (`payment`), unless a factory is already provided. And the factory is easily accessible from the controller by calling `this.get('model').type`. There's no need to convert it to a string (and back).

Here's the relevant code from the Ember Data source.

```
modelFor: function(key) {
    var factory;

    if (typeof key === 'string') {
      factory = this.container.lookupFactory('model:' + key);
      Ember.assert("No model was found for '" + key + "'", factory);
      factory.typeKey = key;
    } else {
      // A factory already supplied.
      factory = key;
    }

    factory.store = this;
    return factory;
  },
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question you posed (unlike another answer), though the information is relevant.