# Set Ember Application View Class for Homepage Only

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-view

**DISCLAIMER:** I'm pretty new to Ember so go easy. :)

I'm attempting to have a class appear that is "is-home" on the div for the application view that gets rendered if the value of App.get('currentPath') is set to 'index'. The code below works for setting the class, however, it **only** does so on load. If you load the page and click a link, the logic is not re-run to remove the class if you navigate away from the homepage or add it if you entered on a different page but then navigate to the homepage. I'm convinced I'm missing something simple.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**Current Code** (Note: I'm using Ember App Kit)

```
// app/views/application.js

export default Ember.View.extend({
  classNameBindings: ['isHome'],
  isHome: function() {
    if (App.get('currentPath') == 'index') {
      return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
  }.property()
});
```

The functionality of App.get('currentPath') is derived from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18302740/3403881.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell the property to update when the `currentPath` property changes.

```
isHome: function() { ... }.property('currentPath')
```

However, I'm not 100% sure if it will find the `currentPath` property on the view since it technically exists on the controller. You might have to watch `controller.currentPath` instead.

Comment: You were right on the view not finding the property. However, `.property('controller.currentPath')` did the trick. Thanks!