# Ember Simple Auth: no need for /login route?

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

Login form in my app is realized via hidden form (which overlays the page and is displayed through data-toggle).

It is nice and user friendly, however the problem occurs when unauthenticated user wants to access protected route - Ember Simple Auth wants to redirect to `/login`. How to display login form in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy - in your application route override an `sessionRequiresAuthentication` action. This action is defined in application-route-mixin, and by default looks like:

```
sessionRequiresAuthentication: function() {
  this.transitionTo(Configuration.authenticationRoute);
},
```

Instead of transitioning you may write a code to open a login form

Comment: But in this action I have to transit somewhere, haven't I? When the user enters the routes url, nothing is rendered yet and the login form isn't put in DOM yet.

Comment: If some route was rendered before, user will stay at that route and login form should be available. But, if user comes to forbidden route directly, you should redirect them somewhere.

Comment: If I override the handling just to do nothing and than I try to access protected route, I get `Error while processing route: about transition is undefined`.

Comment: Ok, maybe I have a better question: How can i tell in the sessionRequiresAuthentication if I am on a blank page or if another route is active or which route was meant to be accessed?

Comment: Which route is meant to be accessed: `var attemptedTransition = this.get('session').get('attemptedTransition'); var route = attemptedTransition.targetName;`. Use console.log to inspect `transition` object, it contains some other info about route, that user tried access to. This answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302463/get-current-route-name-in-ember may (or may not) help to determine if other route was active before.