# EmberJS Print variable outside of template

Tags: ember.js

In my Ember template in my application, I have got a header tag, which should print the title of the current route. Does anyone know how I would accomplish this in EmberJS? Is there any way to set a variable once a route is accessed?

Answer (score 1):

Route

```
Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller) {
    controller.set('routeName', this.routeName);
  }
});
```

Controller

```
Ember.Controller.extend({
  routeName: null
});
```

Template

```
<header>{{routeName}}</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you about `application` template, there is `currentPath` property in Application Controller (and in some other objects too, see details here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/12034

```
//application template
<header>{{currentPath}}</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways.

First, an application controller has a property, `currentPath`. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32749530/2948109) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18302740/2948109) answers you may see examples of using it.

Also, you may use [didTransition](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#event_didTransition) to determine when ember made a transition and update a title in some way.

And finally, if you want to change a document title (displayed in browser tab), there is an [addon](https://github.com/kimroen/ember-cli-document-title)