# Tracking the current URL in a template

Tags: ember.js

I have a "copy link" input in my template that should display the currently loaded URL (with query params) to the user for them to copy & paste.

The input with the URL is part of the template belonging to a parent route that has a number of children:

```
- Parent route  <-- Copy URL link in this template
  - Child route
  - Child route
  - Child route
```

This means that as you navigate the child routes, the URL should update in the parent route. This is turning out to be very difficult to implement.

- AFAIK there is no native event for URL change so I can't create a component and simply track any browser event. I tried `hashchange` on the `window` but this obviously only tracks the `#`and not URL or query params.
- I can't use `window.location.href` when the page loads as any subsequent transitions to the child routes will not be reflected in the input.
- I can't get the URL with `window.location.href` in the `didTransition` action (or any other route hooks) on the parent route because at that point the URL hasn't updated yet (i.e. I get the *previous* URL)

**EDIT:**

At the moment, this is the only approach that seems to work:

```
// In the parent route:
actions: {
  didTransition() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', () => {
      this.set('controller.currentURL', window.location.href);
    });      
  }
}
```

but seems pretty hacky

Comment: Check for a cleaner approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39455543/334913

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Ember 2.15 you can use the [route service](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/RouterService) for this.

Example:

```js
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import { alias } from '@ember/object/computed';

export default Component.extend({
  router: service(),
  currentRoute: alias('router.currentURL')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can benefit from router's location's path property. What I mean is, you can inject `router` to the `controller` you like with an `instance-initializer` and define a computed property to watch the current path. Please check out the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/e1d428a233644499e3dcbba92d7f81a2?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C&route=%2Fother-route). I wrote an instance initializer named `instance-initializers\routerInjector` to inject application's router to every controller. I defined a computed property named `location` within `application.js` controller as follows:

```
location: Ember.computed.oneWay('router.location.path')
```

I added this to `application.hbs`. If I got what you want correctly; this is what you want.