# Get current route name from corresponding loading route in ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-router

As per ember [document](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/) If any model hook in routes taking time to fetch data from server, ember will insert `loading` route. for example `test-loading`, at that time if we try to get current route name like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57512411/8842148), it returns only the loading route.  for example if `sample` route is getting too much of time to load, ember will transition into `sample-loading` until `sample` route resolved. Then again it will change to `sample` route. So at the time of sample-loading `getCurrentRoute` is returns the `sample-loading`. In my case I need to know the actual route name which is changed into `-loading`. I can't find any documentation in internet for doing this. If anyone know the way or idea to implement kindly share with me..

Comment: Can you remove `-loading` from the end of the route name string? Maybe I’m misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

The pragmatic approach is following:

```js
let currentRoute = 'sample-loading';

if (currentRoute.endsWith('-loading')) {
  currentRoute = currentRoute.substring(0, currentRoute.lastIndexOf("-loading"));
}

console.log(currentRoute);
```