# Ember.js get current route

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I'm switching to the new ember router but have a very simple question -- how do I figure out what route I'm currently in? Before you could do something like `App.router.get('currentState')`, but this doesn't seem to work anymore as the router no longer inherits from `StateManager`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019212/ember-app-router-router-currentstate-undefined/15020704#15020704).

Summary: the `currentState` is now stored in the property `currentPath`in your ApplicationController. The accepted solution was to observer this property to write it into a global property:

```
App = Em.Application.create({
    currentPath: ''
});
ApplicationController : Ember.Controller.extend({
    updateCurrentPath: function() {
        App.set('currentPath', this.get('currentPath'));
    }.observes('currentPath')
});
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I wonder if they have purposely removed that functionality though -- why make us go through all of this ourselves just to get the current path?

Comment: Sry, i don't know. I myself never used it programmatically. I just used it for debugging purposes.

Comment: So I just tried this -- seems to work, except I couldn't call ```set``` on the ```App```. All calls to set seemed to fail silently. Instead I just set it directly (```App.currentPath = this.get 'currentPath'```) since I only need this for debugging purposes

Answer (score 6):

I will probably get blasted for this but after a ton of frustration with this I decided to implement a really ugly workaround.

My use case was trying to get the ID of the current post because I was posting a reply to it. Think something like this for our current route:

"...#/post/12345"

my workaround (ugliest code ever):

```
var currentId = window.location.hash.split('/')[2];
 App.Message.createRecord({
      content: message,
      inReplyTo: currentId
    }).get('transaction').commit();
```

Comment: +1 no one can blame you for actually accomplishing what you wanted to, even if it goes along the "ugly" way.

Answer (score 1):

In controller I could get the current route name using the code below. Good luck

this.get("currentRouteName")