# How to get current url (including the part after hash) with Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I need to get current url from Ember as a "redirectTo" parameter. The parameter will be used to redirect users back to the same page after they login from other app. The url looks like

```
http://test.com/apps/#/tables/7
```

I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019212/ember-app-router-router-currentstate-undefined/15020704#15020704) to get currentPath/route from the application. It provides the current route name but I wonder how I can get the complete path including id from Ember. I have a nested route declaration looks like below.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('tables', function() {
    this.resource('table', { path: ':table_id' });
  });
});
```

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Observe the `currentPath` in ApplicationController and update the current URL:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  currentPathDidChange: function() {
    App.currentUrl = window.location.href;
  }.observes('currentPath')
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Panagiotis! I have similar code to observe the currentPath change. Does this mean there is no easy way to get the entire url from Ember?

Comment: AFAIK there's no Ember.js built-in method to get the full href. Don't think it is needed either. Whatever works :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in all cases, and seems to "lag" behind the URL.

Comment: @elsurudo please post an example where this doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Can you just use [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location)?

```
var url = window.location.href;
```

Comment: I tried that but the url doesn't get updated correctly when users click on different table. I can write jquery to observe the url change but I wonder if Ember has a way to do it.

Comment: In my experience, this also will fail while executing integration/acceptance tests. It will always return `/tests`.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks @Panagiotis Panagi, it works.

Furthermore, currentUrl can only be accessed from application controller, so if you want to get it from other place, you can add this code to a certain controller you want to access it :

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['application'],
  currentPath: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application.currentPath'),
    ...

}
```